# How to receive a success response once the PayPal Adaptive Payments pay operation is completed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to integrate PayPal Adaptive Payments into my localhost project. Until now I have managed to perform the paying process. However I need to receive a success response once the payment has been completed in order to update my database.

I have come across the `returnURL` property, however this is not secure for my implementation since the user can just terminate the session before redirecting the `returnURL` and thus the database would not get updated.

I have also come across the `ipnNotificationUrl` however I did not manage to make it work. If this is the right way to achieve this goal what needs to be configured in the coding itself, the Web.config, the PayPal sandbox account, or any other configuration.

What is the best practice to achieve this goal?

Comment: My major problem is to receive the notification in the first place

Comment: You say you are on localhost, so you can't expect paypal to make a callback to that address.

Comment: Is there a type of workaround? I have found this http://demos.ipn-easy.com/Howto/TestEnvironment.aspx but still would prefer something else.

Comment: That's unlikely to work unless you have you router configured correctly.  I'd recommend you set up a test server with a static IP.

Comment: Is there another way how this can be done?

Comment: @JEPAAB - You need to do `UpTheCreek`'s suggestion first.

Comment: @Ramhound It is not possible to me to set up a test server as I am only doing this for educational purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a possible work around to avoid using the `ipnNotificationURL` by using the lightbox feature. Take a look at the following link [Introducing Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro) While using the lightbox feature, the `returnURL` seems to always be called.

The `returnURL` was constructed as follows:

```
    public const string PayPal_URL_Return = YourReturnURL + "/${payKey}";
```

The `${payKey}` is automatically filled in by PayPal itself. Using such information in the returned URL one may call the *PaymentDetails* using the *PayPal Adpative Payments*, and use the transaction details accordingly.

For information regarding the *PayPal Adaptive Payments* visit [AdaptivePaymentsSampleApp](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/Samples/AdaptivePaymentsSampleApp). The file *adaptivepaymentshandler.ashx.cs* contains nearly all the necessary details, together with the *Web.config* file.